# ¿Como configurar libreria SFML de C++ en codeblocks o dev c++?

Tags: c++, sfml

He logrado configurar la libreria SFML en codeblocks pero una vez que muevo el archivo .exe a otro lugar ya no funciona.

Mi configuración es la siguiente:

```
download CODEBLOCK: http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries
download SFML: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/
version: GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit
uncompress: c:\SFMLtdm

Open codeblocks and create a new project with console options.
Settings -> Compiler
    Toolchain executables
        Additional Paths
            C:\SFMLtdm\bin

    Search directories
        Compiler
            C:\SFMLtdm\include
        Linker
            C:\SFMLtdm\lib

    Linker settings
        sfml-graphics
        sfml-window
        sfml-system

    Compiler settings
        #defines
            SFML_STATIC
```

[image: Aplicacion corriendo desde codeblocks][1](https://github.com/quvp861205/SFMLProjects.git)
[image: DLL copiados a la carpeta con la aplicacion .exe][2]
[image: Aplicacion corriendo directamente desde .exe y marcando error][3]

Anexo el codigo fuente:

https://github.com/quvp861205/SFMLProjects.git

Comment: Suena como el típico caso de "*no puedo acceder a la dll*" que se soluciona enlazando estáticamente o copiando la dll adecuada con el exe. Pero no puedo estar seguro sin ver el error que recibes. ¿puedes dar más detalles sobre "*una vez que muevo el .exe a otro lugar ya no funciona.*"?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He consultado con los astros y sacrificado una variable entera sin signo a los dioses supremos del C++, todo para ser capaz de usar poderes de adivinación... voces profundas de los bits bajos me han susurrado binariamente al oído. Y me han dicho lo siguiente:

#### Los binarios enlazados no se corresponden con tu configuración SFML.

Parece que pretendes enlazar estáticamente SFML, por ello defines `SFML_STATIC`:

[image]

Pero de acuerdo con el [tutorial de configuración de Code::Blocks](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php), cuando configuras el enlazado estático debes usar los binarios estáticos, los cuáles tienen el sufijo `-s`: `sfml-xxx-s-d` para Debug y `sfml-xxx-s` para Release, tú estás enlazando con los binarios de enlazado dinámico:

```
Linker settings
    sfml-graphics
    sfml-window
    sfml-system
```

Y por ello, cuando el ejecutable no tiene acceso a las librerías dinámicas (por ejemplo, al cambiar de ruta) deja de funcionar porque las echa en falta. Cambia las propiedades de enlazado para usar las librerías estáticas:

```
Linker settings
    sfml-graphics-s
    sfml-window-s
    sfml-system-s
```

Comment: Espero que tus poderes sobrenaturales le ayuden al OP

Comment: Pues si le agregue el "-s" pero todas maneras al ejecutar directamente el .exe me sigue pidiendo dll's, necesito saber cuales dll's son las que ocupa el exe para que funcione de manera portable.

Comment: Añadiste el sufijo `-s` ¿y te enlazó correctamente o te da fallos al enlazar?